# Google Places radarSearch to get closest 100 places

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

The Google Places API provides a [radarSearch method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) that accepts a single type and an area constraint.  The area constraint can be either a latlng/radius pair or a latlng bounds...

```
var request = {
    location: latlng,  // where latlng is a google.maps.LatLng
    radius: 2000,      // meters
    type: placeType    // e.g. 'restaurant' or 'gas_station', etc.
}
```

or

```
var request = {
    bounds: latlngbounds,  // google.maps.LatLngBounds
    type: placeType        // e.g. 'restaurant' or 'gas_station', etc.
}
```

A radarSearch with either of the above requests will return up to 200 matching places.  If the search actually matches 500 places, only 200 places of the 500 places are included in the response.  There does not appear to be an obvious way to impact **which 200** places are returned.  Initial testing shows it's random, but perhaps biased to returning the places furthest from the center.

The problem is... I'm only interested in the **closest** 100 places.  Is there a supported way to sort the 500 matching places and return the first 200?  I've tried using the 'rankBy' property, but it appears to be ignored...

```
var request = {
    bounds: latlngbounds,  // google.maps.LatLngBounds
    type: placeType        // e.g. 'restaurant' or 'gas_station', etc.
    rankby: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
}
```

The only way to ensure a correct response is to do an initial search with a small area, and successively increase the bounds and re-search, until I get at least 100 places, but not more than 200 places.  Then I can sort in JS and slice to 100 to get my 100 closest places.  Is there a more performant algorithm to get to the same results?

Google has recently deprecated the 'types' property, in which one could specify an array of several matching types.  Currently, only the 'type' property is supported, in which one can only specify a single search type.  I need to support a handful of place types, and now have to do individual searches on each place type and merge.  This change dramatically impacts the performance of my app.  With the above approach, it was taking between 1-3 seconds for a handful of place types, to an unacceptable 20-30+ seconds to do individual searches for each place type.

Are there better ways to get the closest 100 'bars', 'restaurants', or 'cafes', for example?  With Google's change, it now takes 10x longer to get the result.

Appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of further guidance, I was able to implement the following solution...

- Use radarSearch request that includes only location, radius, and single place type
- Launch radarSearches in parallel for each place type of interest
- Each radarSearch adjusts the radius and calls itself recursively
  until the response count is between 100 and 200
- Merge response arrays when all searches are complete, sort on distance, and slice to 100
- The final radius for each radarSearch is cached in localStorage for
  subsequent searches on the same type

The results are quite good.  Cold startup 5-6 seconds, Warm startup (using cached radius values) 300-600ms.  Cache also used for repeated radarSearches within the app session.  This was a better than expected result, although quite an investment to refactor.

Good luck to any visitors reading this.  Hopefully this additional followup is helpful.